# How to prove $\textbf{P}(A\cap B^{c}) = \textbf{P}(A) - \textbf{P}(A\cap B)$

Tags: probability

I want to use $\textbf{P}(A\cap B^{c}) = \textbf{P}(A) - \textbf{P}(A\cap B)$ as a property in a proof but I'm unsure whether I can use it straight away without proving it. I am unsure how to prove it.

Comment: Notice that $A \cap B^\complement$ is the event where $A$ happens _and_ $B$ does not happen, so it is the event where $A$ happens but not $A$ and $B$ simultaneously.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice that $A = A\cap\Omega = A\cap(B\cup B^{c}) = (A\cap B)\cup(A\cap B^{c})$, where 
$$(A\cap B)\cap(A\cap B^{c}) = \varnothing$$
Consequently, it results that
\begin{align*}
\textbf{P}(A) & = \textbf{P}((A\cap B)\cup(A\cap B^{c})) = \textbf{P}(A\cap B) + \textbf{P}(A\cap B^{c}) 
\end{align*}

$\therefore \textbf{P}(A\cap B^{c}) = \textbf{P}(A) - \textbf{P}(A\cap B)$, just as desired.

Comment: Thank you so much :))

Comment: Accept my answer if you think I deserve it.

Answer (score 0):

This is an application of the Additive Rule of Probability, a requirement for probability measure.

- The probability for a union of *disjoint* events equates to the sum of the probabilities for those events.$$X\cap Y=\emptyset\implies\mathsf P(X\cup Y)=\mathsf P(X)+\mathsf P(Y)$$ Taking $X=A\cap B$ and $Y=A\cap B^\complement$, so thus $X\cup Y=A$ and $X\cap Y=\emptyset$ we derive:$$\mathsf P(A)=\mathsf P(A\cap B)+\mathsf P(A\cap B^\complement)$$